# Monitoring Tools in WebSphere Application Server v6.1

Tags: websphere-7, websphere-6.1

How to enable PMI (Performance Monitoring Infrastructure) Data Collection and what is the use of "PMI" in WebSphere Application Server?

What is a "Core Group" WebSphere Application Server?

What is the difference between JSESSION ID and CLONE ID in WebSphere Application Server?

Answer (score 0):

To enable PMI Data Collection you should go through the [WebSphere Documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/tprf_pmi_encoll.html).

The `JSESSIONID` is a standard cookie used by servlet containers to identify your current session (it's the **Session ID**). WebSphere, when working in a clustered environment, uses a [special value](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/Dougclectica/entry/websphere_session_ids22?lang=en) for that cookie which includes the **Session ID**, a **Cache ID** and a **Clone/Partition ID**. The last one from that list identifies the specific WebSphere server instance inside the cluster.

Regarding Core Groups:

> A core group is a high availability domain that consists of a set of
>   processes in the same cell that can directly establish high
>   availability relationships. Highly available components can only fail
>   over to another process in the same core group and replication can
>   occur only between members of the same core group.

More info about them in the [docs](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wsdoc400/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.iseries.doc/info/ae/ae/crun_ha_coregroup.html).